# Google Play will deny the use of location in the background (Warning Email), Expo React native

Tags: android, react-native, expo, google-play-services

We have received an email from google play, where it warns us that one of our apps is using localization in the background, and we have to change that before next year, but I already checked the app and I'm not using localization in the background.

This is the email
[image]

Is this happening to someone else? I don't know what to do because they ask me to remove that service but I'm not really using it

this is my package.json (dependencies I'm using )

```
 "dependencies": {
  "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "2.4.0",
  "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
  "@react-navigation/native": "^5.1.6",
  "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.2.11",
  "axios": "^0.19.2",
  "babel-runtime": "^6.26.0",
  "big-integer": "^1.6.48",
  "expo": "^38.0.0",
  "expo-barcode-scanner": "~8.2.1",
  "expo-crypto": "~8.2.1",
  "expo-file-system": "~9.0.1",
  "expo-media-library": "~8.2.1",
  "expo-sharing": "~8.2.1",
  "firebase": "7.9.0",
  "react": "16.11.0",
  "react-dom": "16.11.0",
  "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-38.0.2.tar.gz",
  "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.3",
  "react-native-camera": "^3.23.1",
  "react-native-fs": "^2.16.6",
  "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.6.0",
  "react-native-picker-select": "^7.0.0",
  "react-native-qrcode-scanner": "^1.4.0",
  "react-native-qrcode-svg": "^6.0.6",
  "react-native-reanimated": "~1.9.0",
  "react-native-responsive-screen": "^1.4.1",
  "react-native-safe-area-context": "~3.0.7",
  "react-native-screens": "~2.9.0",
  "react-native-sha256": "^1.3.6",
  "react-native-share": "^3.3.0",
  "react-native-svg": "12.1.0",
  "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
  "react-native-web": "~0.11.7",
  "react-navigation": "^4.3.7",
  "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0"
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please refer to this docs page: https://docs.expo.io/distribution/app-stores/#android-permissions

> Permissions are configured via the android.permissions key in your app.json file
> By default, your app will include all permissions supported by Expo. This is so that your standalone app will match its behavior in the Expo client and simply "work out of the box" no matter what permissions you ask for, with hardly any configuration needed on your part.
>
> There are some drawbacks to this. For example, let's say your To-do list app requests CAMERA permission upon installation. Your users may be wary of installing since nothing in the app seems to use the camera, so why would it need that permission?
>
> To remedy this, simply add the android.permissions key in your app.json file, and specify which permissions your app will use. A list of all Android permissions and configuration options can be found here.
>
> To use only the minimum necessary permissions that Expo requires to run, set "permissions" : []. To use those in addition to CAMERA permission, for example, you'd set "permissions" : ["CAMERA"].

Comment: So just putting "permissions": [] in my app.sjon should work right?

Comment: yes, doing that and then rebuilding the app would work. but you should verify that you are not using some other apis that require additional permissions to be specified, eg: camera.

Comment: @brentvatne I'm currently using SDK 38. Do I need to upgrade to SDK40 in order to use "permissions" : [] in app.json?

Comment: not necessarily, but you do need to use sdk 40+ for that to have an impact on the background location permission. see this issue for more info and support: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/11918

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

By default, expo adds all permission in the app manifest. To remove all permission
add   `"permissions" : []`   in your app.json file

keep it empty `[]`

example :

```
"android": {
      "package": "com.sahilnetic.appmojo",
      "versionCode": 1,
      "permissions" : []
    },
```

now run

```
expo build:android -t app-bundle
```

then upload the bundle to the google play store